# Finding most highly correlated numerical variables in a broad data set in R

Tags: r, statistics

I have a relatively large data set (8000+ entries and 600 variables). Out of these, about 424 variables are numerical. I'm looking for any significant linear correlations in the data set. To do this, I'm thinking a sample of a few hundred points would be best to feel it out. I've done the following in R to find correlation values, but I find myself stuck after having removed the categorical variables.

```
#Read in data
the_data = read.csv('Example.csv', header= TRUE, na.strings = "^", strip.white = TRUE, skipNul = TRUE)
#Take only numerical data
my_num_data = mydata[, sapply(the_data, is.numeric)]
#Get correlation
cor(my_num_data, use = "p", method = "pearson")
```

I got closer with [this](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/get-top-50-correlated-item-from-a-correlation-matrix-for-each-item-td880675.html), but I still can't figure out how to identify which variables are strongly correlated. My CSV has a useful header, but I strip that away when I throw out all of the non-numerical data.

Comment: I don't think the column header are gone. check `colnames(my_num_data)`

Comment: How do you define a variable of interest? You will need to give more details of what you are trying to do before we can help you with the programming aspects.

Comment: Maybe look into `hetcor` from the `polycor` package. It allows both numerics and factors.

Comment: Ah yeah, I had a mistake in the csv itself that led to all the column names getting messed up. Although I am still at a loss for the best way to do this. `hetcor` seems promising.